# Substract and update from file in swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, nsfilemanager, writefile

I've run into a problem. I've created a file and saved 1000 jsons elements in it.
I want to extract, update, delete a specific json.

I'm creating the file the normal way using `FileManager.default` and writing info to it using `FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: itemPath, contents: data, attributes: nil)`

How can I do that without extracting the entire json array and then writing it again in swift.
I'm thinking something like select interogations etc.

Would be glad if you can help me with this.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, if you don't read the whole file your json will be incomplete and you can't decode it. Maybe look for a solution where you split your data over multiple files or use Core Data or a database solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm looking for something like: Open file -> Write/Delete/Update where I Want -> Close file. Something that doesn't need to rewrite everything.

Comment: And I am saying you can't have that. I could be wrong but I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an index in the file header to record the start position and length of the file corresponding to JSON.

Comment: Okay, so we have the start of the json and the length of it. This means that we have also the end of it. How can I change the content of it without writing again the entire file?